# Integrating $\bar{z}^n$ over a circle

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Evaluate: $$\int_{C(0,1)} \bar z^n dz $$ I am not quite sure how to approach this problem. I am trying to see conceptually what is going on and I am unsure how to approach the integration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to avoid parametrising the curve, you can exploit that $z\bar z = |z|^2$, so on the curve $\bar z = \frac{1}{z}$. Hence
$$
\int_C \bar z^n\,dz = \int_C \frac{1}{z^n}\,dz
$$
which is $0$ for $n\neq 1$, and $2\pi i$ for $n=1$ by any of your favourite tools to compute complex curve integrals (Cauchy's integral formula, residues or the complex version of the fundamental theorem of calculus).

Answer (score 1):

Well first you have to find a parametrization of your object, in the case of this circle you can take

$$\gamma(t) = e^{it} \qquad t \in [0,2\pi].$$

(This is assuming that $C(0,1)$ is the unit circle with center at $0$.)

Then applying the integral transformation formula or path integration formula gets you

$$\int_{C(0,1)} \bar z ^n dz = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \overline{\gamma(t)}^n \gamma'(t) dt.$$

Also see here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration#Contour_integrals